# Polynomial modulus

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can anyone explain why the two solutions to $n^2+7n-2 = 0$ modulo $43$ are $n=13$ and $n=23$ and how they are found?

Comment: Completing the square is a valid process in modular arithmetic. In particular, the quadratic formula holds true when the modulus is odd. Here we have $\Delta=b^2-4ac=57\equiv100$ which has square root $10$. Thus the solutions are $(-7\pm10)/2$; note $2^{-1}\equiv\frac{43+1}{2}=22$.

Comment: Observe $-7\pm10=3,-17$. I've already pointed out $2^{-1}\equiv22$. So then compute $3\cdot22\equiv23$ and $-17\cdot22\equiv13$. Why should you assume two sets of answers are different before you've simplified?

Comment: Then that's the root. You compute the square root of `g` and you compute the inverse of `2` and you compute `(k+sqrt(g))/2`, which *is* what I did in my above comments.

Comment: You compute the square root *modulo whatever number you need to*. Above I computed the square root of $57$ modulo $43$ by observing $57\equiv100$, hence the square root of $57$ is $10$ (well, one of them is).

Comment: Yes, keep adding on the modulus until you find a perfect square. There are more sophisticated methods than this, of course (Andre mentions Tonelli-Shanks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The congruence is equivalent to $4n^2+28n-8\equiv 0\pmod{43}$ (we multiplied through by $4$.) This can be rewritten as 
$$(2n+7)^2-49-8\equiv 0\pmod{43}.$$

Equivalently, we want to solve $(2n+7)^2\equiv 14\pmod{43}$.

Since $86+14=100$, We can probably spot immediately the solution $2n+7\equiv 10\pmod{43}$ and then by symmetry $2n+7\equiv -7\pmod{43}$.

Now we have two linear congruences to solve for $n$, namely $2n+7\equiv 10\pmod{43}$ and $2n+7\equiv -10\pmod{43}$.

To solve the first, rewrite as $2n\equiv 3\equiv 46\pmod{43}$, giving solution $n\equiv 23\pmod{43}$. The other calculation is very similar.

Note that we have essentially used a version of the Quadratic Formula.

**Generalizations:** The procedure we used is *general*. Let $p$ be an odd prime, and consider the quadratic congruence $an^2+bn+c\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, where $p$ does not divide $a$. Rewrite the congruence as $4a^2+4ab+4ac\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, and complete the square as above.

But we are left with a congruence of shape $x^2\equiv d\pmod{p}$. There are easy computational methods to check whether this congruence has a solution. (Half the time it doesn't, and then the original congruence does not have a solution.)

For primes of the form $4k+3$, there is an easy way to compute the solutions when they exist, essentially by using Fermat's Theorem. For other primes $p$, there are good algorithms for solving the congruence $x^2\equiv d\pmod{p}$, even for very large $p$. For details, you may want to look at the Wikipedia article on the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm.

**Remark:** We multiplied through by $4$ to prepare for the generalization. However, in our case we can complete the square somewhat more simply, by replacing $7$ by $50$. Then note that $n^2+50n-2=(n+25)^2-627$, and we can replace $627$ by $25$, making the solutions obvious.

Comment: Yes, multiplying is always going to be the best method.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint I**  Make the polynomial a sum of a square and another number.
**Hint II**  What is $7/2\pmod {43}$?

> Have a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation) if you are not yet familiar with modular arithmetic: Here we are just computing things modulo a prime, namely, if the difference of two numbers is divisible by $43$, then we deem them as equal. And this explains what we meant by the inverse of a number: if $ab$ is regarded as equal to $1$ in our new point of view, then we say that $b$ is the inverse of $a$, and denote by $a^{-1}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea what this is asking me. (n+7/2)^2-57/4?

Comment: You got it! Now just translate everything to modular arithmetic!

Comment: I have no idea how to take it the rest of the way though

Comment: How about the added version?

Answer (score 3):

The number $43$ is a prime, thus we can work like we always do, for example, with real numbers: all the same rules apply to the integers modulo $43$. Now, we seek to **complete the square**. *All equalities are in $\Bbb Z/43\Bbb Z$, the integers modulo $43$*:

$${n^2} + 7n - 2 = 0$$

$${n^2} + 2\frac 72n - 2 = 0$$

Note that $2$ has as an inverse the number $22$ since $2\times 22=44=1 \pmod {43}$. Thus $\dfrac 7 2=7\times 2^{-1}=7\times 22=25$. Then we get

$$\begin{align}n^2+2\cdot 25 n-2+25^2-25^2&=0\\
(n+25)^2&=25^2+2\\(n+25)^2&=25\\n+25&=\begin{cases}5\\-5\end{cases}\\n&=\begin{cases}-20=23\\-30=13\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Comment: Could the downvoter explain? What is wrong?

Comment: I was just giving my opinion in what order the answer should appear on the page. For an OP that is trying to understand "why... $13$ is a solution", 'field', $\mathbb{Z}/43\mathbb{Z}$, $2^{-1}=22$, $2\frac{7}{2}$, may not be an answer. The answer is not for showing that you know, but for making the OP understand.

Comment: @RGB I have posted this with the best intentions. It is true maybe the word *field* is not appropriate, but I don't see why the OP should not be familiar with $\Bbb Z_{43}$ or whatever notation he uses. I explained precisely what I mean by $2^{-1}=22$, for example, and why I wrote $2\frac 72$ since we want to complete a square.

Comment: That's ok. As I said, at the moment I casted my opinion the order resulted in, first the answer with only hints, then mine very basic but inefficient, and then yours, efficient but more advanced.

Comment: @RGB Do you think this answer is not helpful, then? I don't understand what you mean when you "downvote to order". Use downvotes appropriately, please!

Comment: That is not what my vote means. Helpfulness depends on the OP's ability to understand it. My vote meant my opinion on what order the answers should be read.

Comment: @RGB There are very few answers. I find it **useless** to order them in **any** way. Don't you agree? What is the significance in which order these answers are read?

Comment: Assuming RGB hadn't just changed his/her profile moments ago, this is apparently how RGB actually operates, and didn't just make up this voting rationale for this answer alone. Regardless, it's our right to vote how we wish, even if our reasons are seen as alien or unfair by others, and even if the accomplishments ("ordering") of our voting behavior exists only in our minds. You are perhaps too invested if you feel the need to understand why others vote as they do or hope to see meaning or good in them; voting patterns on a spectrum from reasonable to senseless is an inescapable reality.

Comment: @anon Of course that is how he/she operates. I disagree with this. It's as if some guy went around spray-painting houses he deems less worthy to look at as opposed to that nice house down the road.

Comment: @RGB: as viewed by most users that I have discussed this with, upvotes and downvotes are used as a measure of whether an answer is good or bad. People who post good answers will usually take downvotes quite harshly. I don't see that they can be realistically used to order answers since you have only one vote and the answer will probably get many at cross purposes to yours. That being said, voting is capricious. I cannot tell you or anyone else how to vote; that is totally your decision. I am just trying to help explain some of the reactions that your rationale may draw.

Comment: @robjohn I don't want to make this something personal. I don't really care about *this* particular downvote, but rather, about the general idea RGB has on the voting system.

Comment: As I see it, the only *important* use of votes is that answers come to rest in some order, in the long run. Two things should be taken into account. Posts stay in the site, and people often have limited time to read. I, of course, can't control the universe, specially not with a vote in this website. But if I am given the option I will cast my vote, my little grain of sand, according to how I think it is beneficial for the main goals of the site.

Comment: @RGB I have decided to bring this up on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/downvoting-to-rmorder/10475?noredirect=1#10475).

Answer (score 1):

They mean that the remainders of $13^2+7\cdot13-2$ and of $23^2+7\cdot23-2$ are zero after division by $43$.

If two number $n$ and $n+43k$ differ by a multiple of $43$, then the remainders after division by $43$ of $n^2+7n-2$ and $(n+43k)^2+7(n+43k)-2$ are the same. To see this is enough to show that their difference is multiple of $43$. In fact, $\left((n+43k)^2+7(n+43k)-2\right)-\left(n^2+7n-2\right)=2\cdot43nk+43^2k^2+7\cdot43k$, which is multiple of $43$.

This means that to find them it is enough to test the remainders of $n^2+7n-2$ evaluated at each $n=0,1,\ldots,42$, in the division by $43$. The analogous is true in general for any polynomial modulo any number $p$. It is enough to search the zeros among $0,1,\ldots,p-1$.